# Angular JS - custome directive is not getting replaced with actual template

Tags: angularjs, custom-controls

I am learning Angular JS and would like to create my custom directive. 
My javascript code is not showing any error but the custom directive is not getting replaced with my HTML template.
Can you please guide on how to debug this issue or what is wrong with this code?
[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mZDvk/3/)

```
<body ng-controller="customdirectivecontroller">
    <p>Placed custom directive here!</p>
    <mytextbox></mytextbox>
</body>

------------------
var customdirectiveapp = angular.module('customdirectiveapp', []);

customdirectiveapp.controller = ('customdirectivecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = "xxx";
});

customdirectiveapp.directive = ('mytextbox', function () {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */

    directive.template = "My first directive: ";

    return directive;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code

**1)** your variable name is wrong at directive defination it was **customdirectveapp** but it should be **customdirectiveapp**

**2)** your directive definations are wrong you should define controller,directive... like this

```
customdirectiveapp.controller('customdirectivecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
});
```

instead of this

```
customdirectiveapp.controller = ('customdirectivecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
    ....
});
```

and here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLH1U1m4yCsA10jEJYZs?p=preview) of your application

Comment: @PST You are welcome... Was it the answer of your problem or not? I am new here and don't get how people accept answer of their question?