# Angular directive is not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

Electron + AngularJS
I'm doing some basic stuff: I'm trying to add header and footer which will be showed on every page.
So I have **app.js** like this:

```
'use strict';
let app = angular.module('marks', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {})
    .config(($logProvider, $routeProvider) => {

    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'html/home.html'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'html/login.html'
        })
        .when('/teachers', {
            // controller: 'js/teachers.controller.js',
            templateUrl: 'html/teachers.html'
        })
        .when('/students', {
            // controller: 'js/students.controller.js',
            templateUrl: 'html/students.html'
        })
        .when('/404', {
            templateUrl: 'html/404.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });
});
```

**footer.controller.js**:

```
angular.module('marks').controller('MarksFooterController', ['$scope', ($scope) => {}]);
```

**footer.directive.js**:

```
angular.module('marks').directive('marksFooter', () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        controller: 'MarksFooterController',
        templateUrl: '../html/marks-footer.html'
    };
});
```

**marks-footer.html**:

```
<div>
    <h3>2017</h3>
</div>
```

and the same for header.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="marks">
<div class="tile is-ancestor is-12">
    <div class="tile is-vertical is-parent is-9">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
        require('./app.js');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the app, I get no errors, but directives are empty (but they get params as well), so what's the problem?

Screenshot with DevTools :
[image]
 I think that I mess up with controllers somehow, but I'm not sure.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317650/angular-js-custome-directive-is-not-getting-replaced-with-actual-template) doesn't help.
Appreciate any help

**UPDATE**

Now I get it trying to load templates somehow (perhaps some changes with  tag position helped), but app can't find it. `DevTools` -> `Sources` shows no `html` folder ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U063b.png)). Where should I import it?

**SOLVED**
The solution was:

- to import all controllers and directives inside `<head>` of **index.html**
- to change templateUrl to path relative to **index.html**

But I'm still looking how to avoid so many imports inside .html

Comment: Check the network tab for a `404` on the template URL. Keep in mind that the `templateUrl` path is relative to the web root and not the current folder the JavaScript file is located in.

Comment: @cgTag path is fine, no errors in Network tab.  
It's not even trying to load `marks-footer.html`

Comment: Could you post where you are loading your JS? We can't see app.js. I would venture to guess that the `footer...js` files aren't loading.

Comment: @Brian inside <body> in  **index.html**: `<script>require('./app.js');</script>`

Comment: Right, so what is in `app.js`?

Comment: @Brian I updated the answer

Comment: So nowhere in this do you load the footer..js files. You need to load those.

Comment: Also, where are you defining 'require'? That's part of node.js for loading modules. The browser doesn't load using require. Are you trying to use requireJS?

Comment: @Brian I saw this 'require' thing in one of tutorials and it worked the same as if I put `<script>` inside `<head>`. If I also add `<script>`s for directives or controllers, I still get nothing..

Comment: Please add all the js files explicitly in your index.html. Please add according to there dependency i.e. independent component should be added before adding any dependent component. This will surely make it run.

Comment: @Ajay I'm not near my notebook right now, but I will try it. But is there any better to solve it?

Comment: @Ajay Just tried your solution. Pls watch update of question.

Comment: @NikitaPopov Is marks-footer getting loaded? From your screenshot, I can only say that app/src folder is getting loaded in your browser. Can you check why app/html is not loading or app/src is getting loaded in the browser? Server might be hosting only app/src not app/html, if that is the case than you might want to bring all of your code into app/src folder.

Comment: @Ajay I have this [structure](https://imgur.com/a/SYa4v). So app does load some subfolders of `app/src` like `app/src/js` only and throws error when I try to load template from `app/src/html`

Comment: @NikitaPopov For now I think you can provide the html code as inline instead of html path. Also, you might want to use webpack, gulp for packaging these multiple js and html code in one bundle.

Comment: @Ajay okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you including your app.js script. It should be included as  tag in header or in any other place.

Comment: Ok, I had included it to `<head></head>`, and nothing changed. [This tutorial](http://electron.rocks/electron-angular-creating-sample-application/) says to add **index.js** as described. Is it must-have requirement or it should go well without it?